# Open, remove text, and save a text file

Tags: c#, text-files, read-write, system.io.file

I want to edit some text files automatically, but I don't know what to used to do it.

I want to open a file, check all lines, if one line begins with a 'C', I remove first 39-characters, etc .. then save all the file with an other name.

I already have a portion of code :

```
var car = ligne[0];
if(car != 'C') { continue; }
ligne.Remove(0, 39);
```

I use `StreamReader` to read, but what is the simple way to read and save in another file ?

Comment: [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines) → modify lines in memory → [`File.WriteAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx), which opens a file, reads everything, closes the file and returns an array containing all lines.

Do your processing....

Then [File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx) to open a file, write data, and close the file.